# Golang cannot convert []byte("1575455669.4") to float64 using math.Float64frombits

Tags: go, encoding, endianness

I have the following code:

```
x := []byte("1575455669.4")
bits := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(x)
f := math.Float64frombits(bits)
```

On calling `fmt.Println(f)` I expect `1.5754556694e+09`. But instead I end up with `1.451098468672448e-47`

When I try the same conversion through `strconv.ParseFloat(string(x), 64)` I get the correct result. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't just interpret the bytes of a string as float and expect to get a meaningful result.

Comment: Try to covert `1575455669.4` float to byte[] and then to string and then back. See it works. Check what is the string and get surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
x := []byte("1575455669.4")
```

will give you the (UTF-8 encoded) bytes of the `"1575455669.4"` string. This has nothing to do with the memory representation of the floating point number `1575455669.4` which uses the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard. But what you do next would assume just that:

```
bits := binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(x)
f := math.Float64frombits(bits)
```

You have a number given as its base-10 string representation, you have to use `strconv.ParseFloat(string(x), 64)` to parse it and have it as a `float64`.

Comment: Is there any way I can convert []byte directly to float64, without going via a string conversion?

Comment: @IshanKhare Please understand that the `[]byte` you want to convert is nothing else than the base 10 string representation of the number. That needs parsing. If you would have the bytes of the memory representation of a `float64`, for that you may use `math.Float64frombits()`, but that is not what you have.

Comment: To add to icza's comment: consider these two strings: `"255"` and `"377"`. Both represent the same number: one is the decimal representation of 0xff and the other is the octal representation of 0xff. The text `0xff` itself is the hexadecimal representation of that same number (255 decimal, or FF or 377 in hex and octal). Both strings *represent* the all-bits-set byte, but neither *is* the all-bits-set byte. In the same manner, a decimal representation of a floating-point value *represents* the value, but it is not the same as the internal, in-memory storage used in the computer.